How to handle OverflowException Queue is full in Java Project Reactor Flux?
I'm currently troubleshooting an intermittent issue that appears in our logs. Users connect to our application to receive real-time preview updates from backend services. However, when this issue occurs, the flux is unexpectedly cancelled, necessitating a restart of the application.
What perplexes me is that the error seems to occur even when the queue isn't full. I suspect there might be a correlation with user logouts and the subsequent disposal of subscriptions, although it's not consistent.
Here's a brief overview of how our system operates: a web service triggers the onNewPreview function in PreviewListener whenever a new preview is available. The previewDirectProcessor is shared between the Manager and the Listener. Previews are processed in PreviewManager and then moved into a new Flux. Each user subscribes to previewsFlux to receive updates.
Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
The relevant stacktrace is this:
ERROR [boundedElastic-3] reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Queue is full: Reactive Streams source doesn't respect backpressure
Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Queue is full: Reactive Streams source doesn't respect backpressure
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:233)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.onNext(FluxPublishOn.java:233)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyBestEffort$DirectInner.directEmitNext(SinkManyBestEffort.java:359)
    at reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor.tryEmitNext(DirectProcessor.java:233)
    at reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor.emitNext(DirectProcessor.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor.onNext(DirectProcessor.java:217)
    at PreviewListener.onNewPreview(PreviewListener.java:53)

The code we are using is the following (I tried to keep only the relevant part without edit in the flux flow).
class PreviewManager {

    private Flux<Preview> previewsFlux;

    public PreviewManager(DirectProcessor<Preview> previewDirectProcessor) {
        DirectProcessor<Preview> previewUpdates = DirectProcessor.create();
        previewsFlux = Flux.from(previewUpdates)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("preview-processor"));

        Flux.from(previewDirectProcessor)
            .map(previewProcessor::process)
            .onErrorContinue((error, o) -> log.error("Preview processor error", error))
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .onBackpressureBuffer(256)
            .onErrorContinue((error, o) -> {
                log.error("Error processing update in flux " + o, error);
            })
            .doOnNext(previewUpdates::onNext)
            .onErrorContinue((error, o) -> log.error("Error on preview update", error))
            .subscribe();
    }

    public void onUserSubscription(String username) {
        Disposable subscription = previewsFlux
            .filter(preview -> username.equals(preview.getUserName()))
            .doOnNext(preview -> sendMessageToUser(username, preview))
            .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> log.error("Error in preview subscription", throwable))
            .subscribe();
        // Save subscription to dispose it on user logout
    }
}

class PreviewListener {
    private DirectProcessor<Preview> previewDirectProcessor;

    public PreviewListener() {
        this.previewDirectProcessor = previewDirectProcessor;
    }

    void onNewPreview(Preview preview) {
        previewDirectProcessor.onNext(preview);
    }
}


I do not have a precise idea of your current problem, but, as DirectProcessor is deprecated, you might try to replace it with a sink (Ex: Sinks.many.replay(history)), to properly manage backpressure..
